# Should I have all my subroutes inside their direct parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a design question. I currently have about 25 different routes within my application. I define all these routes inside the Dashboard.js. I was wondering if this is a good practice and whether this may hurt performance when loading the app initially since I'm importing all the components to be used in the routes.
Should I each subroutes inside their parent component?

For example:

```
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/teamcalendar" component={TeamCalendar} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/editPreferences/:assignmentId" component={EditPreferences} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/editTemplates/:assignmentId" component={EditTemplates} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/editScheduleTemplates/:scheduleTypeId" component={EditScheduleTemplates} />
<Route path='/dashboard/conversations/:announcementId/employeeId/:employeeId' component={Messenger}/>
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/assignments" component={Assignments} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/reports" component={Reports} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId/editteammembers" component={EditTeamMembers} />
<Route path="/dashboard/team/:teamId" component={Team} />
```

Should I move all these sub-routes inside the Team component? or is it ok to have them in Dashboard?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is okay to have them in one place although it may make more sense to have a component for e.g. all the team routes. Importing does not happen at runtime so performance is not directly affected by imports. Your bundler creates your javascript bundle from what you import in your app. The more dependencies, the bigger the bundle gets. But it does not matter where in the app the import is, als long as you don't use dynamic imports. By the time this runs in the browser everything is already loaded.

Comment: Above is correct but do look at making your routes hierarchical otherwise it is hard to read or maintain.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that @trixn. I didn't know it wouldn't hurt performance.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisCousins, you are absolutely right. I will put them into separate files. Thanks!